# If I revoke iOS Enterprise will the app still work?

Tags: ios, certificate

I am deploying my application via external URL. The application is installed on hundreds of devices all over the world using a Enterprise provisioning profile. The certificate is about to expire with a few days. My question is would revoking the certificate effect any of the existing users? I am aware that new users wont be able to install the application but what about existing users? Will they still be able to use the application correctly? If so do you know a time frame of how long Apple allows the application to work for?

Comment: fire off an email to the relevant department?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Revoking the certificate will make any existing apps fail. I believe the certificates are checked when the device is rebooted.

You need to create another new certificate and update your user's device with a newly built app.

However, even if you don't revoke the current certificate, any existing apps will still stop working when it expires in a few days.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH33-SW13

Comment: The "yes" is kinda misleading, no?

Comment: @mpowered yes, I think I was saying that it will affect the users.

Comment: But "If I revoke iOS Enterprise will the app still work?" is the title, and "Yes" seems like a pretty dangerous answer :-)  Looks like you edited, I think that's much better

Answer (score 5):

> Revoking your distribution certificate will make your app fail on any installed devices.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH26-SW7

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

> Important: Revoking an enterprise distribution certificate invalidates
>   all apps that were signed and deployed with that certificate.

New location

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1868/_index.html