# Revoke Specific Provisioning Profile?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-enterprise

I have an iOS enterprise developer account, which only allows me to have one Distribution Certificate. My distribution certificate is used for several adhoc and enterprise provisioning profiles for several app IDs and a wildcard app ID.

I'd like to revoke the profile for a specific app id, so the builds signed with that profile will no longer launch. Is that possible without revoking the entire cert and having to distribute new builds of *all* apps with new provisioning profiles?

Answer (score 2):

<del>You can revoke the profile and/or the certificate but this will not influence the app already installed.</del>

<del>Only development and Ad-Hoc profiles have a limited live span, InHouse profiles do not have this.</del>

Well I was proven wrong, As apple stated if you [retract a Distribution Certificat](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate.html)e you app will fail to launch. If have test it with a developement certificate and nothing happend. But I can't (read don't want to) test this with the inhouse profile singed with my Distribution Certificate.

Comment: Apple's docs say "If you are enrolled in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program, revoking your distribution certificate will make your app fail on any installed devices." http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate.html from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311393/if-i-revoke-ios-enterprise-will-the-app-still-work