# Will adding push notifications to my ad-hoc certificate break my app for current users?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

Here is my scenario:

- We have an ad-hoc app deployed into production
- In our pre-prod environment, we also deploy our ad-hoc app (same identifier)
- In dev we have **push notifications** working successfully (via Urban Airship)
- To test in pre-prod I need to add Push Notifications to our ad-hoc certificate

Will adding push notifications to the ad-hoc cert affect affect users that have already downloaded the app?  It seems like adding a push notifications cause the ad-hoc cert to have to be re-provisioned.

Thanks for any insights.  I can't find an answer to this in Apple's documentation but they tend to ignore ad-hoc deployments.

Comment: No, installed apps will be fine.

Comment: As @maddy pointed out, I'm actually asking about an "enterprise distribution certificates" which aren't affected as I just need to update provisioning profiles associated with the App Id.  I assume that rings true? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed apps are not affected in any way by changing certificates or provisioning profiles.

You can delete or update your provisioning profiles all you want. The only thing it will affect are any app builds you do after installing the updated provisioning profile into Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I came across this post and it started to make me nervous.  It indicated that existing ad-hoc deployed apps "phone home" when they're started and if the cert isn't there, they stop working.



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311393/if-i-revoke-ios-enterprise-will-the-app-still-work




I know I'm not planning on revoking it, but it's made me nervous about making changes.

Comment: I also see you're talking about provisioning profiles.  So it's actually just provisioning profiles that I'll be updating, my existing ad-hoc doesn't change?

Comment: That other thread you linked to is talking about distribution certificates for enterprise deployment. This question you are asking is about updating an ad-hoc provisioning profile. Not the same thing. Things like setting up push notification or iCloud or Game Center, etc. are associated with the App Ids. Once you update an App Id you need to update the associated provisioning profile(s).

Comment: Will this change things?   Definite confusion on my part.  It **is** an enterprise deployment - we're part of the enterprise dev program and the app is deployed and an installed internally by N number of users.  (I thought "ad-hoc" and "wifi" simply meant "not installed via itunes")

Comment: AdHoc deployment can be done either via WiFi (OTA) or iTunes. Again, you are not touching the distribution certificate. You are only updating the App Id defined in the developer portal and update the provisioning profile used to build the AdHoc version of the app. None of this affects currently built and deployed apps.