# Does iOS enterprise app still work if I delete/edit mobileprovision file or I revoke the certificate file or one of the files expired?

Tags: ios, xcode7, enterprise-distribution, ios-enterprise

I have searched a lot,and also I made a call with Apple Service in the local area,but they are not every professional,and they can't tell me some useful information.

***The problem is:I have developed an iOS app with enterprise distribution,the other people install it,just for testing or showing this app to the other people.I just want to make other people CAN NOT USE it,because later we will distribute this app in App Store.***

The probably same question,one is:
[If I revoke iOS Enterprise will the app still work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311393/if-i-revoke-ios-enterprise-will-the-app-still-work)

As I remembered that a few months ago,when we didn't have enough experience about this,we didn't know the remove of certificate would cause some results,and then the apps already installed on the devices were not working,when we opened them,they crashed,and also we can not install them again!

> But right now,I found that if I removed the mobileprovision file,the
>   app still worked,and also could be installed on the new devices.When I
>   removed the certificate,the app still worked,but could not be
>   installed on the new devices.We uninstalled the app on the old devices
>   and then we could install the app again on the same devices.I don't know the situation when the files expired.

***So the situation has changed right now?***

Note:I build my app and export as an .ipa file with Xcode Version 7.1 (7B91b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody anwsered my question,and I found the not very exact answer.

***When I removed the certificate,the app will not crash AT ONCE.But after a few days,not exactly,I found that the app already installed on my iPhone crashed!***